# Git: Untracking folder only specific branch

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I have a question regarding using a git.

On my "Test" branch, I want to let my git untrack a folder and its sub-files by using the below command. and want to delete this folder in order to improve the build time. (There are over 4000 files and images in the folder and it makes my working branch too slow in building)

git ls-files -z PathToFolder | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged

It works okay, when I just work on this branch. But the problems is when switching to another branch because the deleted folder is not recovered.

What I want

- I want to untrack a folder containing lots files and delete it for I want to improve the jekyll build speed when I am on "Test" branch only, but not other branch.
- When switching to another branch, the deleted folder should be back.

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: This does not *untrack* anything, it just marks the existing index entries so that Git doesn't bother *looking for* a work-tree copy of the file. Note that Git never stores folders at all: it only stores files. You must mark every file (which your `git ls-files -z ...` sequence does).

Comment: @torek Thank you, I am also guessing it is not possible.. I just want to improve my build time by simply deleting all images and some includes file for my test branch.

Comment: You might consider GIt's "sparse checkout" support: make a clone of the repo, enable sparse checkout, and list the files to check out (or not to check out) and Git itself will skip the checkout and set the assume-unchanged bit for those files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the git stash command

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

The working directory would be stored away when you are changing branch, and you can return to this when you need to access your Test branch again.

Comment: Thank your for your attention to my inquiry :)